# determine average length of cells in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, average

Hi I have a cell array in matlab, where the cells are of differing lengths. how do i determine the average length of the cells.

I have tried:

```
mean(length(mycell{:});
```

however this is too many inputs for the mean function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cellfun`

```
mean( cellfun( @length, mycell ) )
```

BTW, for some of the builtin functions it might be better to write

```
mean( cellfun( 'length', mycell ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

If your cell array contains only row vectors or only column vectors, there is an alternative method which doesn't use `cellfun`.

- If your cell array contains row vectors: use either of these:

  `length([mycell{:}])/numel(mycell)`

  `length(horzcat(mycell{:}))/numel(mycell)`
- If your cell array contains column vectors:

  `length(vertcat(mycell{:}))/numel(mycell)`

This answer is faster than [@Shai's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19210233/1714410) if the cell array is small. For moderate or large sizes, or as a general answer, his solution (second version) is better.

Comment: why should this method be faster? Have you tested this? I believe it may be slower since `[mycell{:}]` actually allocates and copies the contents of the cell array into a temp variable only to test its length. I don't have access to Matlab at the moment, but it would be interesting to test which method is indeed faster.

Comment: I thoght faster because it avoids `cellfun`, but you're right, for large vectors it may be actually slower

Comment: `cellfun` is not necessarily slower than other options.

Comment: I have tested and you are right, `cellfun` with `'length'` is fastest. I'm updating my answer

Comment: My answer is fastest only for small arrays. For example, it is fastest with `mycell = num2cell(ones(1,20));` (but then again it's probably not so important to gain speed when the cell array is small)

Comment: In your example, there is no need to copy elements when concatenating `mycell` into a single array - because it originated from a continuous array. If elements of `mycell` are not continuous in memory, I expect to see a difference.

Comment: +1 for the thorough investigation.

Comment: +1 for motivating that investigation (and editing the link) :-)

Comment: thanks guys - interesting and useful discussion.